# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 122; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, xsd

I am using spring and having an issue

My `servlet-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="somepackage"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
     p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
    </beans>
```

Exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 122; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

line number 6 is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">`

I have search the similar issues as there are many and tried them but dint work.

I have checked my internet connection and also tried converting the url by removing version number but dint work.

I dont want to download ans store those xsd file locally but if my connection is working the why I am having this problem I also tried cleaning eclipse cache

Can anybody help me?

After @Jens my project worked but IDE showing some error shown below

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>
> - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document    'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd',
>     because 1) could not       find the document; 2) the document could not
>     be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
> - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no    declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following lines to 
** xsi:schemaLocation**

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
```

Your line no 6 will be then

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd"
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the scemaLocation for beans:

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

And i  would recommand that you remove the version of the xsd. It make easier to migrate to an other version

Comment: @codegasmer can you revalidate the file. It is the same as in the other answer so i'm confused about the error.

Comment: @OK the it looks like a refresh problem